# Wealthy man learns to astrally project from old book, travels to another planet and takes over a dying boy

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm searching for the title of a novel on 'astral projection' I read some years back.

It's about a wealthy man who learned astral projection from a long lost book. He then traveled to another planet where he was able to take over the body of a dying boy.

It's not the *Palos* trilogy.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)